# Нужна помощь с формами в с++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Как мне передать значение переменной?
[image: Скрин]

```
#pragma once
#include "MyForm2.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

namespace Проектсформой {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm1
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //

    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox10;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm1::typeid));
        this->pictureBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->comboBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
        this->pictureBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->comboBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
        this->comboBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
        this->comboBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
        this->pictureBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->pictureBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->pictureBox10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox3))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox4))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox5))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox2))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox6))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox7))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox8))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox9))->BeginInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox10))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox3
        // 
        this->pictureBox3->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ButtonHighlight;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox3, L"pictureBox3");
        this->pictureBox3->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
        this->pictureBox3->Name = L"pictureBox3";
        this->pictureBox3->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::pictureBox3_Click);
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ButtonHighlight;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox1, L"pictureBox1");
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox4
        // 
        this->pictureBox4->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlLightLight;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox4, L"pictureBox4");
        this->pictureBox4->Name = L"pictureBox4";
        this->pictureBox4->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox5
        // 
        this->pictureBox5->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlLightLight;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox5, L"pictureBox5");
        this->pictureBox5->Name = L"pictureBox5";
        this->pictureBox5->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::pictureBox5_Click);
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this->comboBox1->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
        this->comboBox1->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
        this->comboBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->comboBox1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(7) {resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items1"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items2"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items3"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items4"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items5"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox1.Items6")});
        resources->ApplyResources(this->comboBox1, L"comboBox1");
        this->comboBox1->Name = L"comboBox1";
        // 
        // pictureBox2
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox2, L"pictureBox2");
        this->pictureBox2->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
        this->pictureBox2->Name = L"pictureBox2";
        this->pictureBox2->TabStop = false;
        this->pictureBox2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::pictureBox2_Click);
        // 
        // comboBox2
        // 
        this->comboBox2->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
        this->comboBox2->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
        this->comboBox2->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->comboBox2->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(7) {resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items1"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items2"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items3"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items4"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items5"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox2.Items6")});
        resources->ApplyResources(this->comboBox2, L"comboBox2");
        this->comboBox2->Name = L"comboBox2";
        // 
        // comboBox3
        // 
        this->comboBox3->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
        this->comboBox3->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
        this->comboBox3->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->comboBox3->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(7) {resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items1"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items2"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items3"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items4"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items5"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox3.Items6")});
        resources->ApplyResources(this->comboBox3, L"comboBox3");
        this->comboBox3->Name = L"comboBox3";
        // 
        // comboBox4
        // 
        this->comboBox4->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
        this->comboBox4->DropDownStyle = System::Windows::Forms::ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
        this->comboBox4->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->comboBox4->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(7) {resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items1"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items2"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items3"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items4"), 
            resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items5"), resources->GetString(L"comboBox4.Items6")});
        resources->ApplyResources(this->comboBox4, L"comboBox4");
        this->comboBox4->Name = L"comboBox4";
        // 
        // pictureBox6
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox6, L"pictureBox6");
        this->pictureBox6->Name = L"pictureBox6";
        this->pictureBox6->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this->label1, L"label1");
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        // 
        // pictureBox7
        // 
        this->pictureBox7->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Menu;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox7, L"pictureBox7");
        this->pictureBox7->Name = L"pictureBox7";
        this->pictureBox7->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox8
        // 
        this->pictureBox8->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Menu;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox8, L"pictureBox8");
        this->pictureBox8->Name = L"pictureBox8";
        this->pictureBox8->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox9
        // 
        this->pictureBox9->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Menu;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox9, L"pictureBox9");
        this->pictureBox9->Name = L"pictureBox9";
        this->pictureBox9->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox10
        // 
        this->pictureBox10->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Menu;
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox10, L"pictureBox10");
        this->pictureBox10->Name = L"pictureBox10";
        this->pictureBox10->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // MyForm1
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this, L"$this");
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlLightLight;
        this->ControlBox = false;
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox10);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox9);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->comboBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox3);
        this->DoubleBuffered = true;
        this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
        this->MaximizeBox = false;
        this->MinimizeBox = false;
        this->Name = L"MyForm1";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::MyForm1_Load);
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox3))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox4))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox5))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox2))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox6))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox7))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox8))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox9))->EndInit();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox10))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void MyForm1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { Show();
            int mas[4] ;
            int a;
            srand(time(NULL));
            for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
            {
                a=rand()%7;
                mas[i]=a;
            }

         }
private: System::Void pictureBox3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {Close();
         }
private: System::Void pictureBox5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             MyForm2 ^ F2;
             F2=gcnew MyForm2();
             F2->Show();

         }
private: System::Void pictureBox2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


         }
};
```

}

[image: Вот эти pictureBoxы]

объясниите мне как сделать, чтобы при проверке щелкая на кнопку индексы с комбобоксов совпадали с цифрами из массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам, по сути, надо хранить некое состояние между вызовами различных методов класса (в данном случае обработчиков событий загрузки и щелчка).

Для этого и были созданы поля класса — вынесите массив туда.

```
// ...

private: int mas[4]; // <--- Выносим сюда

private: System::Void MyForm1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Show();
    int a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        a=rand()%7;
        mas[i]=a;
    }
}

// ...

private: System::Void pictureBox2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    // Обращаемся к mas[i] так же, как и в MyForm1_Load.

// ...
```